# how to handle race condition with Runnable using separate thread for lambda inside hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, hashmap

I was getting a code review from my software mentor (who is a C# programmer). He recommended I use lambda in my application to avoid using a large chain of `if/else if` statements. I created a hashmap with two types `String` and `Runnable`.

He said it looks good, but now we have a problem where there is a race condition... meaning Runnable is creating a separate thread, and if the `Runnable.run()` thread does not win the race it could cause problems down the line (especially being in the constructor).

Here is the sample code to show the problem...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class testLambda {
    String[] numArray = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    testLambda(String num){
        Map<String, Runnable> printNumbers = new HashMap<>();

        printNumbers.put(numArray[0], () -> printStringOne());
        printNumbers.put(numArray[1], () -> printStringTwo());
        printNumbers.put(numArray[2], () -> printStringThree());

        printNumbers.get(num).run();
    }

    private void printStringOne(){
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    private void printStringTwo(){
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    private void printStringThree(){
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new testLambda("Three");
        new testLambda("Two");
        new testLambda("One");
    }
}
```

There are a couple solutions where I am not sure to handle either of them...

- Somehow place a hold on the current thread until the Runnable thread has completed execution, and using some type of `join` after it's been completed to let the current thread continue running.
- Instead of using Runnable for executing the lambda void type expression, somehow use something else where it will execute a void type lambda.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is no race condition because all the runnables are executed on the main thread. There will be a race condition if you were to use something like this `new Thread(printNumbers.get(num)).start()` and your methods were accessing the same object(s).

Comment: I see, your right > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run. Thanks, my worries of this are over :)